# can't get gulp to use browser-sync to refresh an express server and json

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, reactjs, gulp

I'm learning react and the first thing I wanted was a development environment that could handle the reloading and refreshing for me. I'm following along with their tutorial here:

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

Now I wanted to add gulp into this setup. The server ( https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/blob/master/server.js )works fine on its own but doesn't have browser-sync and all the extras that come along with gulp of course.

so what I did was change the server's port to 9000 and proxy the browser-sync in. However, the proxy doesn't seem to pass ajax calls to the server so it can write the json. I've included my gulpfile here.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var sass        = require("gulp-ruby-sass");
var filter      = require('gulp-filter');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var sourcemaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var server      = require('gulp-express');
var reload      = browserSync.reload;

gulp.task('server', function(){
  server.run(['app.js']);

  browserSync({
    proxy: "localhost:9000"
  });

  gulp.watch("./scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
  gulp.watch("./app/**/*.html").on('change', reload);
});

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return sass('./scss', {sourcemap: true})
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.error('Error!', err.message);
    })
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('maps', {
        includeContent: false,
        sourceRoot: './app/css'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/css'));
});

gulp.task('html', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

// Watch scss AND html files, doing different things with each.
gulp.task('default', ['server'], function () {
  gulp.watch("./scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
  gulp.watch("./app/**/*.html", ['html']);
});
```

**And here's the app.js file. You can see how it's trying to handle the json.**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/comments.json', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile('_comments.json', function(err, data) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(data);
  });
});

app.post('/comments.json', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile('_comments.json', function(err, data) {
    var comments = JSON.parse(data);
    comments.push(req.body);
    fs.writeFile('_comments.json', JSON.stringify(comments, null, 4), function(err) {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
      res.send(JSON.stringify(comments));
    });
  });
});

app.listen(9000);

 console.log('Server started: http://localhost:9000/');
```

**Other things I've tried**

Before using a proxy. I tried to switch browser-sync's middleware to the express server I had. The problem I ran into is the documentation for this seems to assume I know what I'm doing with express enough to make it work (I mean, the documentation pretty much just shows a console.logged example. Pretty useless).

**using middleware**

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var sass        = require("gulp-ruby-sass");
var filter      = require('gulp-filter');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var sourcemaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var reload      = browserSync.reload;

//server shit
var fs          = require('fs');
var path        = require('path');
var express     = require('express');
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var app         = express();

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

    browserSync({
        server: {
          baseDir: "./app",
          middleware: function (req, res, next) {
            app.use('./', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app')));
            app.use(bodyParser.json());
            app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

            app.get('./comments.json', function(req, res) {
              fs.readFile('_comments.json', function(err, data) {
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.send(data);
              });
            });

            app.post('./comments.json', function(req, res) {
              fs.readFile('_comments.json', function(err, data) {
                var comments = JSON.parse(data);
                comments.push(req.body);
                fs.writeFile('_comments.json', JSON.stringify(comments, null, 4), function(err) {
                  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
                  res.send(JSON.stringify(comments));
                });
              });
            });

            next();
          }
        }
    });

    gulp.watch("./scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("./app/**/*.html").on('change', reload);
});

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return sass('./scss', {sourcemap: true})
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.error('Error!', err.message);
    })
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('maps', {
        includeContent: false,
        sourceRoot: './app/css'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/css'));
});

gulp.task('html', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

// Watch scss AND html files, doing different things with each.
gulp.task('default', ['serve'], function () {
  gulp.watch("./scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
  gulp.watch("./app/**/*.html", ['html']);
});
```

Comment: You need to use the `bs.relaod()` task. For example https://github.com/agconti/sun-clock/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Comment: inside server.run somehow? I'm not sure how to connect those two things.

Comment: Can you access `http://localhost:9000/comments.json` from your browser? If you can, does `http://localhost:3000/comments.json` work?

Comment: so I started going down the middleware route again to see if there was something I missed but thus far my results have been the same.

Comment: CONTINUED: (but I don't have the proxy in my git history. doh! so I can't say if 9000 works or not).

- running gulp brings me up a server pointed at the folder I expect. It's loading the data from the json as expected
- if I fill the form and click submit it shows the comment get added, then removes it again.
- checked the logs. READING and putting the data on the screen seems to work just fine. When it tries to write the json I get: comments.json error Not Found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is nodemon! nodemon will just restart the server when it sees a change. I don't have to mess with middleware or anything. Then I just proxy browser-sync.

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['sass'], function() {

browserSync({
  port: 7000,
  proxy: "http://localhost:5000",
  files: ["app/**", "scss/**.*.scss"]
});

  gulp.watch(sassFolder + '**/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(distFolder + '**/*.html').on('change', reload);
});

gulp.task('nodemon', function (cb) {
  return nodemon({
    script: 'server.js',
    ignore: [
      './bower_components/**',
      './node_modules/**',
      './build/**'
    ]
  }).on('start', function () {
    cb();
  });
});
```